# Javascript Function only works with onclick or setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, raphael

I'm trying to make a website which adjusts itself to the window size. One problem I have is the vertical alignment. I made a jQuery function to manage it, the function works fine for div with images but not very good for a div with a lazy line painting which uses [RaphaelJS](http://lazylinepainter.info/).

The strange thing is that the function works when I call it with an onclick or if I set a timeout for like 50ms (not in the following `jsfiddle site`, but maybe it's an problem of `jsfiddle`).

My question is what is the problem?

Can I call automatically call the function without to set a timeout? Is it because of the lazy line painting?

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/checkerbrazze/emFN8/)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, CheckerBrazze.

I trimmed down your question a little bit and added some white space to make it more readable.  Your second question, with a little bit of rework, would be on-topic here.  You'll really should ask it as a second question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any code, I would image that you may need to call your function once the DOM has finished loading.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // vertical alignment function here
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify -- the code in his fiddle is using jQuery's `ready`which means the DOM has loaded.  Your solution uses the `load` which waits until all of the CSS and images have loaded and *everything* is ready.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is one part of the solution. The other part is that instead of using `$('#blwfshL').height()` I had to calcute the height dynamically which isn't a problem, because I do this in a the lazy line painting function before :)